# OverlayFS - Understanding and writing files

Tags: overlayfs

I'm working on getting a reliable image for a kiosk style application.  Currently one of our big issues is boot stability.  Since there's a high likelihood of our computers being hard-reset or losing power, a frozen/stuck boot is a common fault state for us.

To try to counter this, someone suggested making the root partition read-only.

That's fine, but I'm not sure how I can download content onto the device (and keep it there through reboot)

I was thinking of making two partitions, one with the OS and one for file storage.  Would this work in OverlayFS?  Does this create any issues?

Comment: Do you need overlayfs for that? Creating a separate partition for the Downloads (or home) directory and mounting root read-only should be enough for that, I think.

Comment: The attractive part of overlayfs is being able to change the underlying system if i want to without too much hassle.

Comment: and remounting root rw is a huge hassle? O.o